# Creating a Breeze DenseMatrix using an existing List of Lists in Scala

Tags: scala, linear-algebra, scala-breeze

I've a

```
List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3))
```

and I want to create a Matrix/DenseMatrix with 3 rows and 9 columns so that I can perform some Linear Algebra operations on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not great syntax for this yet. I actually ran into it today, so I'll probably add better support for it soon. In the meantime, DenseMatrix(array1, array2, array3) works. So:

```
val listOfLists : List[List[Int]] = ???

DenseMatrix(listOfLists.map(_.toArray):_*)
```

Not the prettiest, but I'll add better support if you open a ticket.

Comment: Thanks. I should open a ticket at Github. Correct?