# Converting a Row Matrix into a Breeze Dense Matrix

Tags: apache-spark, scala-breeze

I have an MLLIB distributed row matrix in which row order doesn't matter. Is there any way to easily convert this into a breeze dense matrix? I'd imagine a row-by-row mapping might work, but I'm relatively unfamiliar with breeze as a whole.

Edit: Using `X.rows.map(x => x.toArray)`, I've managed to convert it into an RDD of the form org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]]. I believe this is a step in the right direction...

Comment: Did you try doing a `collect` of the RDD and then converting it into a breeze matrix?

Comment: Hmm, using collect on the RDD, I end up with: `breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Array[Double]]`. What I need is `breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double]`. Thanks for the suggestion, however. I believe I just need to convert the array into a a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a collect on your RDD. It'll return you an `Array[Array[Double]]`.

`val array = your_rdd.collect()`

One to convert the array of arrays into a matrix would be to do the following:

`val dm = DenseMatrix(array.map(_.toArray):_*)`

Part of the answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204398/creating-a-breeze-densematrix-using-an-existing-list-of-lists-in-scala). Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Changed my answer to this as it is more concise. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to convert to an array if the type is already `Array[Array[Double]]`, you can just use `DenseMatrix(array:_*)`

Answer (score 2):

Ended up getting it working with the below code.

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV, DenseMatrix => BDM, sum}
val arr = X.rows.map(x => x.toArray).collect.flatten
val dm = new BDM(X.numRows().toInt, X.numCols().toInt, arr)
```

Thanks, @ar7 for hte help.