# Create a Breeze DenseMatrix from a List of double arrays in scala

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I have a structure `List[Array[Double]]` and I want to convert to a DenseMatrix. I have this solution but I think there might be a better way:

```
val data = List[Array[Double]]
val rows = data.length;
val cols = data(0).length;
val matrix = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](rows, cols)
for (i <- 0 until data.length) {
  for (j <- 0 until data(i).length) {
    matrix(i,j)= data(i)(j)

  }
}
```

I've been through the Breeze docs but didn't find anything. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
val matrix = DenseMatrix(data:_*)
```

**EDIT1**

For an explanation of how it works, you can consider `data: _*` as expansion into variable arguments. For example if

```
val data = List[Array[Double]](Array(1.0, 1.0), Array(2.0, 2.0))
```

Then `DenseMatrix(data:_*)` is same as saying `DenseMatrix(Array(1.0, 1.0), Array(2.0, 2.0))`

For more details:

- [Syntax sugar: _* for treating Seq as method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar-for-treating-seq-as-method-parameters)
- [Creating a Breeze DenseMatrix using an existing List of Lists in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204398/creating-a-breeze-densematrix-using-an-existing-list-of-lists-in-scala?rq=1)

Comment: It works. I just don't understand the meaning of (data:_*)

Comment: @MLeiria Updated post with explanation.